# How to express language switching in an use-case diagram?

Tags: use-case, language-switching

Use case diagram is "A list of steps, typically defining interactions role and a system, to achieve a goal." (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case).

Login should not be included in use-case diagram, according to http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.7340.13: "Logging in is just a by-product of other use cases"

How about language switching on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally prefer to have that documented in the Requirements Specification alongside with a list of selectable languages. You already indicated the reason: The user's goal is typically not to read the correct language but to achieve an actual business goal. So it's just a prerequisite.